# How can I list the names of all modules in a long .wl file?

Tags: files-and-directories

I have a .wl file with lots of utility modules, for example

```
SEIR = Module[{ss, ee, ii, rr, dyn, X, inf, pars},
  ss = b - μ s - β s i + γr r;
  ee = β s i - e (μ + γe);
  ii = e γe - i (μ + γi + δ);
  rr = γi r - (γr + μ) r;
  dyn = {ee, ii, rr, ss};
  X = {e, i, r, s};
  inf = Range[2];
  pars = {b, μ, β, γe, γi, δ, γr};
  {dyn, X, inf, pars}
  ]

    DFE[dyn_,X_,inf_]:=Solve[Thread[dyn==0]/.Thread[X[[inf]]->0],X];
```

Is there a command to list the *names* of all the modules? They are saved in a file *util.wl*.

But the commands `<<util.wl` and the suggested

```
Cases[Import["util.wl", "HeldExpressions"], m_Module :> Hold[m], Infinity]
```

do not display the desired answer, *SEIR, DFE*.

Comment: I am not sure you are using the term "module" in the usual sense of Mathematica: module refers to the symbol `Module` and nothing else. Are you really after all the top-level symbols defined by a given `.wl` file? If yes, I suggest you take a look at `BeginPackage` and friends. Because then, querying all the definitions made by a `.wl` file is as simple as ``?util`*``

Comment: Thanks.  I did not want to create a package,  since this process complicates modifying and  debugging for amateurs like me, but I get your point that if it's not a package, it is not easy to query it

Comment: You don't have to create an actual package (see also my answer) - you simply need a few lines of extra code at the beginning and end of your file for this to work. (The only "tricky" part is that you should reevaluate the entire file whenever you make any edits, rather than reevaluating only the cell containing the modified code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you adopt the standard [`BeginPackage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BeginPackage.html)/[`EndPackage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EndPackage.html) paradigm for your `.wl` file. Your example file would then become:

```
BeginPackage["util`"];
SEIR; (* or SEIR::usage = "some description of SEIR"; *)
DFE;

Begin["`Private`"]

SEIR = Module[{ss, ee, ii, rr, dyn, X, inf, pars},
  ss = b - μ s - β s i + γr r;
  ee = β s i - e (μ + γe);
  ii = e γe - i (μ + γi + δ);
  rr = γi r - (γr + μ) r;
  dyn = {ee, ii, rr, ss};
  X = {e, i, r, s};
  inf = Range[2];
  pars = {b, μ, β, γe, γi, δ, γr};
  {dyn, X, inf, pars}
  ]

DFE[dyn_,X_,inf_]:=Solve[Thread[dyn==0]/.Thread[X[[inf]]->0],X];

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

You can then inpsect the definitions provided by your file as follows:

```
<<util.wl
?util`*
```

[image]

This format has many other advantages, such as:

- Private variables that should not be visible are actually hidden inside a private context
- You actively declare what you want to be visible, ideally by providing a usage message for each symbol
- The symbols are grouped into their own context

Comment: Unfortunately, after packaging, I do not know how to call the modules. A simple dyn=SEIR[[1]];dyn//MatrixForm yields \!\(
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", "", 
TagBox[GridBox[{
{
RowBox[{
RowBox[{"model`Private`i", " ", "model`Private`s", " ", 
          "model`Private`\[Beta]"}], "-", 
RowBox[{"model`Private`e", " ",

Comment: That's because the symbols `i`, `\[Beta]`,... were not declared in the "public" part of the package. Your code should still work as normal, the symbols will just have long names. If you don't want/need the isolation, you can remove the ``Begin["`Private`"]`` & `End[]` lines, but be aware that then all symbols will be returned ``?util`*``. You could try to filter out the ones that have no definition attached to them, but that depends on what exactly you are after. The usual recommendation is to either expose symbols in the public part of the package, or to take them as arguments to the function

Comment: Indeed, adding symbols before Begin["`Private`"] resolved the problem. But now ?util`*  returns besides  the six names of Modules also the 100 variables they use. I never need more than two utilities at a time, so I'm getting a list of 70 variables I don't use. Is there a way to hide them?

Comment: Another alternative might be to do ``$ContextPath=DeleteDuplicates[Append[$ContextPath,"util`Private`"]]`` after the `EndPackage[]` line (instead of adding all symbols before the ``Begin["`Private`"]`` line). That way, you can keep the symbols in a separated context, while still having them display nicely. However, the problem with both approaches is that you are introducing all these symbols with short names onto the context path, which might lead to problems later down the line. At some point, you might really be better off with something like what @userrandrand suggested in the comments.

Comment: Unfortunately, this last line did not stop all variables from printing as model`Private`...

Comment: That's strange... I assume you replaced `util` by your actual context name (I guess that would be `model`?)? Can you edit your question to include the content of the file as it is now?

Comment: Yes, it works!  (I had a typo)

Answer (score 2):

To only list all `Module`s:

```
Cases[Import["util.wl", "HeldExpressions"], m_Module :> HoldForm[m], Infinity]
```

To keep also the assignments:

```
Cases[Import["util.wl", "HeldExpressions"], 
  HoldPattern[a_ = m_Module] :> HoldForm[a = m], Infinity]
```

If by *modules* you mean various `Set`s and `SetDelayed`s, then:

```
Cases[Import["util.wl", "HeldExpressions"], 
 HoldPattern[Set[var_, __] | SetDelayed[var_, __]] :> HoldForm[var], 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work -- see edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to work"? It should output a list of `Modules`. What do you get?

Comment: Sorry, it seems I get all the modules, but actually I just wanted their names

Comment: @florin I did not try but maybe `Cases[Import["file.wl"], f_?(Not[DownValues[#] === {}] &) :> f, All]`. Functions have `DownValues` whereas regular symbols do not.

Comment: This seems more transparent  (and hence better for me) than defining a package, but  it did not work.

Comment: @florin, please see my update.